# Unity build errors using C# Tasks

Tags: c#, visual-studio, win-universal-app, unity-game-engine

I am trying to update and build a C# project in Unity 5.6.1 to later be run on the Hololens. Originally, the project used System.Threading, but I think that I need to use Tasks instead because of some issues with Unity.

When I open the project in Visual Studio, it runs fine using Tasks. When I build the project in Unity, it says that Tasks do not exist (error below).  I am building with .Net 4.6 in Unity on Universal 10 SDK.

```
using System;
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Text;

namespace SampleCSApp
{
    // Based on http://answers.unity3d.com/questions/357033/unity3d-and-c-coroutines-vs-threading.html
    class BaseThread
    {
        private bool _isDone = false;
        private object _handle = new object();
        //private System.Threading.Thread _thread = null;
        private System.Threading.Tasks.Task _thread = null;
        private static int WAIT_FOR_MS = 100;

        public bool IsDone
        {
            get
            {
                bool tmp;
                lock (_handle)
                {
                    tmp = _isDone;
                }
                return tmp;
            }
            set
            {
                lock (_handle)
                {
                    _isDone = value;
                }
            }
        }

        public virtual void Start()
        {
            _thread = new System.Threading.Tasks.Task(Run);
            //_thread = new System.Threading.Thread(Run);
            _thread.Start();
        }
        public virtual void Abort()
        {
            _thread.Dispose();
            //_thread.Abort();
        }

        protected virtual void ThreadFunction() { }

        public void WaitFor()
        {
            while (!IsDone)
            {
                _thread.Wait(WAIT_FOR_MS);
                //System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(WAIT_FOR_MS);
            }
        }

        private void Run()
        {
            ThreadFunction();
        }
    }
}
```

Unity error given:

> Assets/SampleCSApp/BaseThread.cs(14,34): error CS0234: The type or namespace name `Tasks' does not exist in the namespace `System.Threading'. Are you missing an assembly reference?

Comment: You should use a existing free threading library from the store, the code example you used is not the greatest.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unity is based on .NET 2.0 with some .NET 3.5 features thrown in. Tasks is a .NET 4.0 feature. You need to wait for Unity 2017.1 to be released (or use [the beta version](https://unity3d.com/unity/beta)) which will support .NET 4.6 via a opt-in option. See [this forum post](https://forum.unity3d.com/threads/future-plans-for-the-mono-runtime-upgrade.464327/) for more details.

> We wanted to let everyone on the forum know our future plans for the
>   Mono runtime upgrade.
>
> The Unity 2017.1 release will be available as a public beta soon. In
>   this release, the Mono runtime upgrade feature will be an option. For
>   a given project, you can choose to use the existing version of Mono in
>   Unity (with .NET 3.5 support) or the new Mono runtime (with .NET 4.6
>   support). In Unity 2017.1, the default setting is to use the older
>   version of Mono. Soon (maybe the 2017.2 release of Unity) we will make
>   the new Mono runtime default, with the old runtime as an option. Later
>   still, we will remove support for the old runtime. More details will
>   be coming in a blog post soon, but we wanted to let everyone on this
>   forum know first.
>
> We really appreciate the time, effort, and feedback so many of you
>   have provided to move this process forward. Our team is focused on
>   shipping the Mono runtime upgrade to all of the Unity users without
>   breaking things. The work you have put in to find many of the things
>   that did break is invaluable.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, Scott, that makes sense. In Unity Build Settings -> Player Settings -> Other Settings -> Configuration -> Api Compatibility Level there is a .NET 4.6 option. Do you know what that would be used for?

Comment: Have not actually played with any of the new scripting stuff yet, so no.